# how to replace a string with equal(=) sign

Tags: jquery, regex, replace

I am trying to replace all the strings with certain value, that is i want to     replace  this string imgclose="" with only imgclose.
I tried this

```
xmlString.replace(/^imgclose=""/, "imgclose")
```

Comment: also you can use `str.substr(0, 8)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the `^` the RegExp will only match the strings that starts with `imgclose=""`, if you want to match any `imgclose=""`  you need to remove the `^`. If you want to replace any occurrence  of the string you need to add `g` modifier.

The final RegExp will look like this:

```
xmlString.replace(/imgclose=""/g, "imgclose")
```